# No "new" objects for Java Spring and how to convert legacy application to "Spring" concept

Tags: spring, legacy-code

I have just started learning Java Spring and the concept of Dependency Injection (DI) and Inversion of Control (IoC).

I learned that all objects whether it is singleton, prototype or request and sessions, are all retrieved from the container.

The container manages the dependencies between classes and the lifecycle/scope of the object.

The fundamental idea behind this is there are no "new" operators for application using Spring Framework as the backbone of the system. (Please correct me if I am wrong).

I wanted to modernize legacy applications coded without the Spring framework and manages the 3rd party libraries classes and injects them using Spring.

How should I approach this?

Comment: I don't see how we could answer such a vague question, but the idea that you should never use new because you're using Spring is not correct. It's as incorrect as saying that you should never use `if` because you use polymorphism. Use Spring components when they make sense, to model stateless components of your architecture: controllers, services, DAOs. If you start looking up prototype beans from the Spring context instead of using new, something's wrong.

Comment: @JBNizet  "If you start looking up prototype beans from the Spring context instead of using new, something's wrong"  why shouldnt prototype bean injected using Spring? 

Based on my understanding, I can look up prototype bean using the container.

Comment: The key here is lookup vs. inject. Injecting beans is fine. That's what dependency injection is all about. Looking up beans in the context "because new is evil" just makes your code messier for no reason, and is exactly what dependency injection tries avoiding. Use Spring to define a clean, testable architecture, using AOP to handle transactions, etc. Don't use it to avoid new.

Comment: @JBNizet ok, what is the difference between lookup and inject? If I have a Hibernate entity to be used on my page beans (JSF), should I use Autowired or new operator?

Comment: Inject means that you autowire a component B into A and use B from A. Lookup means that you call context.getBean() from A to get a B instance. Entities should be created using new. What would you gain by NOT using new and look it up instead? Entities, by definition, are not handled by Spring. They're handled by Hibernate.

Comment: @JBNizet wouldnt it be better if I can specify it as a prototype scope and Spring returns me a new entity everytime I lookup the entity within the container?

Comment: No, it wouldn't. What would you gain? Is `Foo foo = new Foo()` less clear or slower than `Foo foo = springContect.getBean(Foo.class);`? Doing that is the inverse of dependency injection.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77394/discussion-between-optimus-and-jb-nizet).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I learned that all objects whether it is singleton, prototype or request and sessions, are all retrieved from the container.

That is not quite right. Not *all* objects, but those you have the cotainer told to resolve, are retrieved from the container. In general you use the `@Component` [annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Component.html) to mark which of your objects should the container know of. Besides `@Component` there are other annotations which do in principle the same, but allow a more finegrained semantics, e.g. `@Repository` [annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Repository.html), which is at its base `@Component` and put `@Target`, `@Retention`, `@Documented` on top.

> The container manages the dependencies between classes and the lifecycle/scope of the object.

Yes. The container does the wiring up for you, i.e. resolving dependencies annotated with `@Ressource`, `@Autowired` or `@Inject` depending on which annotation you prefer.
During the `lifecycle` there are possible events, which allow usage of [lifecycle](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-lifecycle) callbacks.
Also: You could determine the [bean scope](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes).

> The fundamental idea behind this is there are no "new" operators for application using Spring Framework as the backbone of the system. (Please correct me if I am wrong).

The fundamental principle is, that you delegate the *creation* of objects of a certain kind to the container. Separation of `creation` and `consumption` of objects allows greater flexibility and in consequence better testability of your application.

Besides the "components" of your application, there are e.g. the typical *containers* like *ArrayList* or *HashMap*, upon which you use the *new*-operator as before.

> I wanted to modernize legacy applications coded without the Spring framework and manages the 3rd party libraries classes and injects them using Spring.
>
> How should I approach this?

From what was said above, it should be "simple":

**1)** Go through each class file and look for its dependencies

**2)** Refactor those out and put `@Component` on top of the class
Special case: 3rd party objects, where you do not have access to the source. Then you have to wrap its construction yourself into a *factory* e.g. with [@Bean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java-bean-annotation).

**3)** Add the missing dependencies via `@Autowired` (the spring specific annotation for marking dependencies)

**4)** Refactor components of the *service layer* with `@Service` [annotation](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/36830-what-is-the-service-annotation)instead of `@Component`.

**5)** Refactor the data access layer, instead of using `@Component`, you can use `@Repository`.

This should give you a base to work with.

Comment: "The fundamental idea behind this is there are no "new" operators for application using Spring Framework as the backbone of the system. (Please correct me if I am wrong)." You may have @Bean methods where you use the "new" operator as part of the Java Configuration. However as you said it is *important* that the container manages the object and that **you** do not instantiate objects yourself.